# Can't ping my MFP from Windows, but can by Linux

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, printing, dhcp

I have a trouble. Can`t access to my ethernet-connected MFP from Windows 7 clients, but by Ubuntu (and router/server) machine it can get access to it.

MFP = Epson Stylus Color 730

network:

MFP (192.168.0.100) + win7clients (192.168.0.101-200) ---> Ubuntu server/router (192.168.0.1) ---> Internet

MFP get right IP and settings form DHCP server. On Windows machines disabled all firewalls and so on.

From Ubuntu I can do with MFP what I want, but why I can`t even ping it form Windows?

Thanks

Edit:

Content of **/etc/sysctl.conf** :

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

#kernel.domainname = example.com

# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
#kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3

##############################################################3
# Functions previously found in netbase
#

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable Spoof protection (reverse-path filter)
# Turn on Source Address Verification in all interfaces to
# prevent some spoofing attacks
#net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
#net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies
# See http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/
# Note: This may impact IPv6 TCP sessions too
#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1


###################################################################
# Additional settings - these settings can improve the network
# security of the host and prevent against some network attacks
# including spoofing attacks and man in the middle attacks through
# redirection. Some network environments, however, require that these
# settings are disabled so review and enable them as needed.
#
# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
# _or_
# Accept ICMP redirects only for gateways listed in our default
# gateway list (enabled by default)
# net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
#
# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
#
# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#
```

Edit 2:
After some fixes - all, except of me in local net can use MFP.
So, new puzzle:

My local network:
http://prntscr.com/kvk5g

"Hakuhonoo" can`t see MFP, but other do.

Content of **/etc/iptables.conf**:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Fri Nov  9 01:51:58 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [23:1420]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [20:18904]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 224.0.0.0/4 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 224.0.0.0/4 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80:85 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1985 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 60000:65000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 81:85 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov  9 01:51:58 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Fri Nov  9 01:51:58 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [377:31747]
:INPUT ACCEPT [39:3558]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11:872]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7:570]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 81:85 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.101
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov  9 01:51:58 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Fri Nov  9 01:51:58 2012
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1425:140833]
:INPUT ACCEPT [762:69219]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [495:56655]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [643:122295]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1152:179096]
-A PREROUTING -d 224.0.0.0/4 -p udp -j TTL --ttl-inc 1
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov  9 01:51:58 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your Ubuntu to forward packets?
Enable routing: (taken from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing))

1. Configure the gateway for routing between two interfaces by enabling IP forwarding:

   `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"`
2. Edit /etc/sysctl.conf, and (up to 10.04) add these lines:

   `net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1`
   `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1`
3. From 10.10 onwards, it suffices to edit /etc/sysctl.conf and uncomment:

   `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: 1) yes, I done it; 2) no, but I try it tomorrow, thanks; 3) yes, I have it too. Also I add all of this file contents to the question.

Comment: is there any difference between your computer and the others? (static ip maybe?)

Comment: yes, it have a static IP = 192.168.0.101; I need to forward some ports [81..85] to my computer. You can see it in iptables.conf

Comment: try to set an IP address not from the DHCP range you set in the server. (It has to be in the same subnet, maybe somthing like 192.168.0.2)

Comment: No, it don`t work. I change 192.168.0.101 --> 192.168.0.3 and printer static 192.168.0.100 --> 192.168.0.2